# If $A\subseteq B$ then $\cup A\subseteq \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\subseteq B$ then $\cup A\subseteq \cup B$

My try:

If $x\in \cup A$ if there is $C \in A$ such that $x\in C$

Using the hypothesis: $A\subseteq B$,

$C\in B$ then

$x\in B$ then

$x\in \cup B$

Comment: "If $x\in \bigcup A$, then $x\in A$" This part is not true. If $x\in \bigcup A$, this tells you there exists a set $C$ such that $x\in C\in A$.

Comment: What is the difference between $A$ and $\bigcup A$ for example?

Comment: True. That is the part im struggling with. What you recomend?

Comment: $x \in \bigcup A$ iff there is $C \in A$ such that $x \in C$. If $B \subseteq A$ then $C \in B$.

Comment: $ \cup A = \{x | \exists a \in A, x\in a \} $

Comment: Also $\cup A=\bigcup_{a\in A} a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this, you just need to work from the definitions.

- You're assuming that $A \subseteq B$, so you know that if $a \in A$, then $a \in B$.
- You need to prove that $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$. By the definition of $\subseteq$, this means you need to prove that, for all $x$, if $x \in \bigcup A$ then $x \in \bigcup B$.

So assume $x \in \bigcup A$. Then:

- By definition of $\bigcup A$, it follows that $x \in a$ for some $a \in A$;
- Next, look at how you can apply the assumption that $A \subseteq B$;
- Finally, use the definition of $\bigcup B$ to deduce that $x \in \bigcup B$.

By definition of $\subseteq$, it follows that $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$.

Comment: Thanks. Looks better now?

Comment: @SebasMartinezSantos: Not quite, in your edit you have said that $x \in B$, but you need to have $x \in \bigcup B$. It would also be useful to say why the fact that $x \in \bigcup B$ means that the proof is finished.

Comment: Thank you vey much.